# Finding encryption algorithm from source and resulting string

Tags: string, algorithm, encryption

If we have a source string and encrypted string, can we find out algorithm/forumla used in encrypting that source string?

**EDIT**

Here are a couple of such strings.

string, encrypted string
avtacarguy,c0e54a662e8d7adbf26e2515dcb2bfde
burris212,0c9fe74ce3abb1507108dba1f04497e5
directert,96336189003e59a2d4a3fdbb2cf02707

Comment: Do you know if it's a modern algorithm(DES, AES,...) or a history one(Caesar, letter substitution,...)?

Comment: @aioobe
No don't have the key

Comment: @CodeInChaos
Don't know either

Comment: Create a bunch of example ciphertext-plaintext pairs. Some of them should have related plaintext (replace a single letter for example). If it's a historic cipher you might discover a structure. If it's a modern cipher, you're out of luck. You'll need to find the algorithm and key by reversing the software in question.

Comment: I have given some example strings. See my edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. There can be numerous algorithms that turn the source string into the encrypted string, based on what public and/or private keys are used.

In simple cases, such as the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) it may be possible to figure out how it was done but even then you've only provided a 'most likely' explanation as to what encryption algorithm was used.

Comment: Sorry, we just don't know enough. Even with some samples it's going to be tough.

Answer (score 3):

Technically (mathematically) speaking, no. Several encryption schemes could yield the same crypto text for some particular input.

If you had had the encryption key, you could of course try out all popular encryption schemes and see if you got some exact match in which case you could be pretty sure you found the algorithm.